# SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python

Meu programa ta dando "SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing", meu professor disse que seria por não fechar o while, mas não consigo, já tentei de varios jeitos, continua dando erro

```
class Conta:

    def __init__(self,cod,nome,saldo):
        self.cod = cod
        self.nome = nome
        self.saldo = saldo

    def getNome(self):
        return self.nome

    def setNome(self,Nome):
        self.nome = Nome

    def getCod(self):
        return self.cod

    def setCod(self,Cod):
        self.cod = Cod

    def getSaldo(self):
        return self.saldo

    def setSaldo(self,Saldo):
        self.saldo = Saldo

    def deposito(self):
        novaQuantia = float(input('Informe o valor do depósito:\n'))
        self.saldo = self.saldo + novaQuantia

    def saque(self):
        saque = int(input('Informe o valor do saque:\n'))
        if saque <= self.saldo:
            self.saldo = self.saldo - saque
            return True
        else:
            print('Saldo insuficiente!')
            return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
        a = 0
        codigo = []
        nome = []
        saldo = []
        while a != 7:
            print('1 - Inserir\n')
            print('2 - Excluir\n')
            print('3 - Alterar\n')
            print('4 - Consultar\n')
            print('5 - Operação\n')
            print('6 - Listar\n')
            print('7 - Sair\n')
            try:
                a = int(input())
                if len(codigo)!=len(nome) and len(nome)!=len(saldo):
                            raise Exception("Informação incompleta!")

                if a == 1:
                    try:
                        codigo = int(input('Informe o código da conta: \n'))
                        nome = str(input('Informe o nome do titular: \n'))
                        saldo = float(input('Informe o saldo da conta: \n'))
                        codigo.append(codigo)
                        nome.append(nome)
                        saldo.append(saldo)
                    except ValueError:
                        print("Valor inválido!")

                if a == 2:
                    try:
                        p = int(input('Informe a posição a ser removida:\n'))
                        codigo.pop(p)
                        nome.pop(p)
                        saldo.pop(p)
                    except IndexError:
                        print("Index inválido!")

                if a == 3:
                    try:
                        codigo = int(input('Informe o código da conta: \n'))
                        saldo = int(input('Informe o novo saldo da conta: \n'))
                        saldo.pop(codigo.index(codigo))
                        saldo.insert(codigo.index(codigo),saldo)
                    except ValueError:
                        print("Código inválido!")  

                if a == 4:
                    try:
                        codigo = int(input('Informe o código da conta a ser consultado: \n'))
                        print("Código: {} | Nome: {} | Saldo: {}".format(codigo.index(codigo),saldo.index(saldo),nome.index(nome)))
                    except ValueError:
                        print("Código inválido!") 

                if a == 5:
                    try:
                        b = int(input('Informe a operação a ser feita:\n'))
                        print('1 - Realizar saque\n')
                        print('2 - Realizar depósito\n')
                        if b == 1:
                            self.saque()
                        else:
                            self.deposito()
                    except ValueError:
                        print("Código inválido!") 

                if a == 6:
                    try:
                        for codigo, nome, saldo in zip(codigo, nome, saldo):
                         print("Código: {} | Nome: {} | Saldo: {}".format(codigo, nome, saldo))    
                    except ValueError:
                        print("Código inválido!") 

                if a == 7:
                    print("Operação finalizada!")
```

Comment: Está faltando o `except` do  `try` dentro do `while`, só isso.

Answer (score 0):

Como Giovanni disse, está faltando terminar um `try` com `except`.

Aliás, neste caso em particular, só é necessário um `try`:

```
while a != 7:
           try:
                if len(codigo)!=len(nome) and len(nome)!=len(saldo):
                            raise Exception("Informação incompleta!")
                ...
                if a == 7:
                    print("Operação finalizada!")
           except ValueError as e:
                print(e)
           except IndexError as e:
                print(e)
           except Exception as e:
                print(e)
```

Se der qualquer `ValueError` dentro deste `try`, ele irá jogar para o `except`; sem exceções (piada intended).
E também não há necessidade de utilizar um `try` aninhado a outro `try`, pois essa declaração serve para tratamento de erros, e seria redundante tratar um erro dentro de outro erro.

Comment: A questão do precisar apenas um `try` é bastante questionável e quase sempre vai contra a ideia de exceção, pois costuma-se ser interessante tratar uma exceção específica de um bloco limitado de código.

Comment: Disse mais no caso do código dele em específico, já que só há apenas `ValueError` e uma exceção genérica `raise Exception`, mas tentar ser mais direto.